# set monitor resoution for a different user in Lubuntu 17

Tags: command-line, display-resolution, monitor

I have been using Lubuntu 17 for several months - I like it. I just purchased a different monitor with 1360x768 resolution as pposed to the 1600x900 that I had been using. I made the mistake of trying to set this as the resolution from the desktop. Wen I logged out and logged in again I get a no signal display on the monitor. Then like a fool I loged in as a different user and did the same thing with the same result. The other 3 user accounts I have are still useable. If I go back to the 1600x900 monitor I get the same problem.

My question is - where can I get into the individual user's monitor settings to fix them using the command line?

I saw a post about .config/monitors.xml but that file does not exist for any of the users.

Looking for enlightenment....

Comment: Actually,  through the magic of automatic updates I am now using 18.04, if that makes a difference..

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to say I have been able to find the answer to my question..

The culprit was a file named ~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop
which contained....

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=LXRandR autostart
Comment=Start xrandr with settings done in LXRandR
Exec=sh -c 'xrandr --output VGA1 --off'
OnlyShowIn=LXDE
```

commenting out the "Exec" line or even better deleting the file entirely solved the problem.. Guess I was too lazy to look up the correct xrandr parameters.. but I noticed that the other accounts that were working did not have this fie...